# How to change default middleware redirect

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Default redirect of this middleware is /home. How or where can I change it ?

```
public function __construct(){
   $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `User` get redirected to `$redirectTo`defined in
`Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController`. Update this to your needs.

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Comment: I solve the problem by creating my own middleware, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer ..

open app/http/middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('home'); // <-- change this to  redirect()->back();
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```